# Tailwind classes from my library on NPM not being picked up

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I've made a simple component library for React and Tailwind which I'm publishing to NPM.

I need the library to use Tailwind styles from the project that's importing it. EG if colors are overridden in the project, then I need the component to use these colors and not Tailwind's defaults.

When I import a component it renders on the page correctly, but the classes aren't picked up by the Tailwind compiler, so the component is unstyled.

I can get it working by adding the path to the library in my tailwind config:

```js
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "node_modules/my-library/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", // Added this
  ],
```

However, I don't love the developer experience of having to do this. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New Answer

I understand your question now. And to be honest I am not able to think of a simple solution for this. Tailwind doesn't follow the dependency graph - so you have to specify the path like how you are doing right now.

If there are multiple such modules from where you would like to extract styles, then you may write a function that appends the path for you. This will improve the DX to some extent.

```js
function getPathToModule(moduleName) {
    return `node_modules/${moduleName}/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}`
}
```

### Old Answer

When you build your component library, you will get a separate `.css` output which bundles all the CSS needed by your library. You can just import that CSS file in your App and the styles would be working.

```js
// App.tsx
...
import 'my-library/styles.css'
...
```

If you want the library styles to be isolated from the default styles, then a simple solution would be to modify all classes within the library with some prefix. Tailwind provides this [prefix configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) which you can use for this purpose. This prefix configuration will be in your library config and not the actual application config. This will just modify your internal library classes and the classes in your application will be unaffected. No complicated config for overriding of classes is required here because the class names are different (prefixed). Hence there will be no conflicts.

Comment: I don't want the styles to be isolated, in fact I want want the opposite. As I said in my question, if the projects that imports the library overrides a colour, then I need the library to use that overriden color value.

Comment: Oh, I see. Let me recite to make sure I understand the question correctly. You are using tailwind classes in your library and if they are overridden in the project - For example, if the `p-6` style is changed to something else, then that new style should be used. Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Comment: Does your library bundler generate a bundled CSS?

Comment: Not currently no.

Answer (score 1):

When importing the library you also need to import the CSS file which is generated by tailwindcss when project is built, which you can see in your build or dist folder.

`import { MyLibrary } from 'my-library`

`import 'my-library/dist/style.css'`

To make CSS file importable, in `package.json` add export for CSS file.

```
"exports": {    
  ".": {
    "import": "./dist/my-library.es.js"
   },
  "./dist/style.css": {   <--- add this
    "import": "./dist/style.css"
   }
},
```

You can see example from this npm library [github repo](https://github.com/musama619/react-photo-editor/blob/main/package.json)

Comment: the main problem is why we need to import `style.css` file from our package. why tailwindcss is not working without `style.css`

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach? As I said in my original question, if the project that imports the library overrides a color value then I need the library to use the overridden color value. Wouldn't importing the CSS file in this way not do this?

Comment: @KannuMandora i faced the same issue with my library, only found this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use the `@apply` directive in your component's styles to apply Tailwind classes from your project.

if your project has a custom color scheme defined in your Tailwind config, you can use the `@apply` directive to apply those colors to your component's styles, like so:

```
.btn {
  @apply bg-purple-500 text-white;
}
```

This will ensure that the component uses the custom colors from your project instead of Tailwind's defaults.

another option is to use Tailwind @layer directive in your component's CSS file. This will allow you to override any Tailwind classes that are imported from the library, using your project's custom colors or other customizations.

if you have a component called "MyButton" in your library which uses the Tailwind class `bg-blue-500`, you can override this in your project's CSS file as follows:

```
@layer components {
  .bg-blue-500 {
    background-color: red; // Use your project's custom color instead of Tailwind's default blue.
  }
}
```

by this component will use your project's custom colors instead of Tailwind's defaults. but this will only work with classes imported from the library. If you are using custom classes or inline styles in your components, they will not be affected by the @layer directive.

Comment: Using @apply seems to have no difference vs using the class names normally.